# Index and value parameters of a function passed to .attr()

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

In the below code,

```
<div>Zero-th <span></span></div>
<div>First <span></span></div>
<div>Second <span></span></div>

<script>
    $( "div" )
      .attr( "id", function( index, value ) {
        return "div-id" + index;
      })
      .each(function() {
        $( "span", this ).html( "(id = '<b>" + this.id + "</b>')" );
    });
</script>
```

---

We have `.attr("id", function( index, value ){..})` query selection method, that takes function to compute attributes for the set of matched elements

Is `index` parameter, an index of DOM element collection within jQuery object `$('div')`?

Is `value` parameter, the DOM element(`div`) within jQuery object `$('div')` ?

Answer (score 2):

> A function returning the value to set. `this` is the current element. Receives the index position of the element in the set and the old attribute value as arguments.

Source (and a lot more information): http://api.jquery.com/attr/

You can also just use `console.log(index, value);` to find out about the parameter values.

The index starts with 0 and is the index position of your div - in your case it would be 0-2. The value is just the old value of the attribute, it will be empty in your case. The result:

```
Zero-th (id = 'div-id0')
First (id = 'div-id1')
Second (id = 'div-id2')
```

Btw, you should alway aim for a solution without jQuery, usually it does not take more time to use Vanilla JavaScript, at least not anymore. For example, a quick test with the same result:

```
var index = 0;
[].forEach.call(
  document.querySelectorAll('div'), 
  function(el){
    el.setAttribute('id', 'div-id' + index);
    el.querySelector('span').innerHTML = '(id = "<b>' + el.id + '</b>")';
    index++;
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The callback function for the [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) function is called for each element in the jQuery matched set. Since your matched set is created using the selector `'div'`, it will contain all the `<div>` elements in the DOM.

The first parameter to the callback function (`index`) is the index of the element within the matched set. So if you have three `<div>` elements in the DOM, you will have three elements in your matched set. The indexes will therefore be 0 through 2.

The second parameter to the callback function (`attr`) is the current value of the attribute for the element.

If you want to reference the element in the callback function, you can use `this`, since it is the context for the function call. Note that `this` refers to the DOM element, not a jQuery object. If you want a jQuery object, use `$(this)`.